# Is it possible to configure Mockito mock to call multiple answers on a single invocation?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a test which tests a bunch of classes and I have to stub a void method. The stubbed behavior should always invoke one callback and in some cases the second one in addition depending on the invocation arguments.
Here is my test code, method names represent what I am trying to accomplish.

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
    {
        callback.thisShouldBeAlwaysCalled();
        return null;
    }
}).when(service).foo(any(Bar.class));

doAnswer(new Answer<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
    {
        callback.thisShouldBeCalledInAdditionInSomeCases();
        return null;
    }
}).when(service).foo(argThat(new CustomBarMatcher(42)));
```

Currently I have to use if statements in the answer() body to cover these use cases combined with any(Bar.class) matcher, but it would much easier and cleaner to use custom matchers instead.
Is it possible to configure Mockito mock to call multiple answers on a single invocation?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking: the title says "different answers for different matchers", the question says " multiple answers on a single invocation". Mockito only executes the first match.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the question title.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want. Could you extend your question with some example code showing what you wished was possible?

Comment: The short answer is no. Because `Answer` can return a result (as used in `thenAnswer`) it would be odd to have a built-in mechanism for Mockito to call multiple `Answers` for the same mocked invocation. I think @AndyTurner has given you your best option.

Comment: @JohnB - what non-null result can be returned by Answer? It can only be Void, which is not instantiable.

Comment: Thanks guys, the argument with return value certainly clears this up. I have ended up writing something similar to what Andy Turner has suggested.

Comment: @AndyTurner in this case the OP has specified that `Answer` return `Void`. However, `Answer` is generic and could just as easily be `Answer<String>`. So my point is, how could you call multiple answers from same invocation of a mock? Which `String` would the mock return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to create a composite Answer:

```
final Answer answer1 = ...;
final Answer answer2 = ...;
Answer compositeAnswer = new Answer() {
  public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    answer1.answer(invocation);
    answer2.answer(invocation);
    return null;
  }
};
```

There might be a utility method that exists to build this composite for you.

So to finish, use:

```
doAnswer(compositeAnswer ).when(service).foo(any(Bar.class));
```

Comment: I'm confused by the edit somebody else made to my answer. What is answer3? Why is it not simply a matter of calling `doAnswer(compositeAnswer).when(service).foo(condition) `?